# Spring Boot 2.5.3 OAuth2 - Auth-Server and Webservice separate, Login error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, okta, spring-oauth2

Following the example on https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/03/12/oauth2-spring-security-guide using the projects `Create an OAuth 2.0 Server` and `Build Your Client App` I cannot get it running without error.

I don't use `Thymeleaf`, as my Webservice returns data, not a page.

OAuth 2.0 Server project

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class Demo2Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    public AuthorizationServerConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }    
    
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("abcd")
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("fDw7Mpkk5czHNuSRtmhGmAGL42CaxQB9"))
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
            .scopes("user_info")
            .autoApprove(true)
            .redirectUris("http://localhost:8082/login/oauth2/code/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");;
    }
}


@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("john")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("doe"))
            .roles("USER");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }    
}

@RestController
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/user/me")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }    
}

application.properties
server.port=8090

pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>     
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>           
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I omit the context path, which the project originally uses.

Webservice project

```
@RestController
public class MyRESTController {

    @GetMapping("/securedPage")
    public String securedPage(Principal principal) {
        return "securedPage";
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Principal principal) {
        return "index";
    }   
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
    }
}


application.properties
server.port=8082
server.servlet.session.cookie.name=UISESSION

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.client-id=abcd
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.client-secret=fDw7Mpkk5czHNuSRtmhGmAGL42CaxQB9
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.client-name=Auth Server
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.provider=custom-provider
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.scope=user_info
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8082/login/oauth2/code/
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.client-authentication-method=basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.authorization-uri=http://localhost:8090/oauth/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.token-uri=http://localhost:8090/oauth/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8090/user/me
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.user-name-attribute=name

pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When running both porojects, with `localhost:8082` in the web browser I get `index` as response.

With `localhost:8082/securedPage` I get redirected to the login page, entering username `john` and password `doe` I get the following error page:

```
Login with OAuth 2.0
[invalid_user_info_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the UserInfo Resource: 404 : [{"timestamp":"2021-07-30T07:58:54.529+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/user/me"}]

Auth Server
```

Don't know what the error is causing. Looks like it is related to the Webservice application property and the URL to the `UserController` in the OAuth 2.0 Server project

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8090/user/me
```

One additional question is:
Can the login form be avoided? The credentials passed somehow.
If the client is not the web browser but some other application which has no UI. Or perhaps curl. I also have MockMvc tests, so far it was Basic Auth, now OAuth2, how will be those affected?

Comment: Your `UserController` is in the wrong project it has to be in your OAuth 2.0 Server project.

Comment: Yes, your right.. in the hurry I must have placed it wrongly.

Comment: Works, thanks. I looked many times over it, didn't recognize that :)

Comment: Just one question added... can the login form be avoided?

Comment: What kind of authentication do you want? Do you want basic instead of form? That should go. However, you should not enter the user name and password in your client app.

Comment: This issue question is solved, but I cannot mark the correct answer, because you did that with a comment. My next problem is described in a new issue question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68618739/spring-boot-2-5-3-oauth2-auth-server-and-webservice-separate-after-login-no-e

Comment: You could close your question as "Cannot reprocue or typo". That's the best/regular way for such questions. Click on "close" and then on "community". I will look at your other question.